# Filter rows using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

After executing some SQL query, I get some records for two fields: order_id and status_id as below:

```
 order_id           status_id
---------------------------------
'102764334679', 'ITEM_PROCESSING'
'102764334679', 'ITEM_PROCESSING'
'102764334679', 'ITEM_PROCESSING'
'112202812293', 'ITEM_PROCESSING'
'112202812293', 'ITEM_COMPLETED'
'112217253712', 'READY_TO_PACK'
```

How can I fetch count of order_id's which are having status_id as 'ITEM_PROCESSING' and if an order_id has more than one status_id, then it will not be counted .

For example , for above records, final count will be 1 because order_id '102764334679' has status as   'ITEM_PROCESSING' in all its rows while order_id '112202812293' has multiple status_id . so it will not be counted.

Comment: Add your SQL query please.

Comment: select   order_id,status_id from omsnew.order_item where order_id in (select  order_id from omsnew.order_header where status_id='ORDER_PROCESSING')

Comment: If you need more than one status_id, it must be a different table to deal with correctly. Or update it instead of creating a new registr

Comment: Actually, for every order, there are some items in order_item table with some status. I want to count number of orders in order_item table which are having all status as 'ITEM_PROCESSING'. If there is a single item with some different status then that order will not be counted

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I am using MySQL

Comment: Sample data as 1,2 ,3 and A, B, C is easier to get than '102764334679', 'ITEM_PROCESSING'
'102764334679', 'ITEM_PROCESSING'
'102764334679', 'ITEM_PROCESSING'
'112202812293', 'ITEM_PROCESSING'
'112202812293', 'ITEM_COMPLETED'
'112217253712', 'READY_TO_PACK'.

Comment: My mistake, just see the last digits of order_id

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select count(distinct order_id)
from t
where t.status_id = 'ITEM_PROCESSING' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.order_id = t.order_id and t2.status_id <> 'ITEM_PROCESSING'
                 );
```

Although the above might be the most efficient, I would be intended to solve this using double aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.order_id
      from t
      group by t.order_id
      having min(status_id) = max(status_id) and min(status_id) = 'ITEM_PROCESSING'
     ) tt;
```

Comment: Thanks boss, you are awesome. your query returns correct result. You are true genius.